# How to append new user entries to a csv file in java?

Tags: java, csv, printwriter

I'm using the printResults method to "save" user inputs to a csv file. However currently the issue is that instead of updating the csv file with new entries it is currently overwriting the previous entry. I'm not sure if I'm suppose to use a for loop to help me achieve this. Some help would be appreciated on this!

```
 public void printResults(double distance, double MPG, String fuelType, double result)
    {
        try(PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new File("output.csv"))){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Distance:,");
            sb.append("MPG:,");
            sb.append("fuel type:,");
            sb.append("Cost:,");
            sb.append('\n');
            sb.append(distance+",");
            sb.append(MPG+",");
            sb.append(fuelType+",");
            sb.append(result);

            printWriter.write(sb.toString());
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("An error has occured because:");
            alert.setContentText("The csv file does not exist!");
            alert.showAndWait();

        }
```

Comment: If you want to append the new rows, why are you writing the column headings every time?

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that mistake. I have fixed it. I have changed it to  try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output.csv",true)){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            
            sb.append(distance+",");
            sb.append(MPG+",");
            sb.append(fuelType+",");
            sb.append(result+"\n");
            
            fw.write(sb.toString());

Comment: You can't edit a csv like we do in our computers. you WILL HAVE TO CREATE A NEW CSV. This new csv should have the data of the old csv and then you should add your new data. Ofcourse the name of the new file can be same as the old one and the old one would be replaced.